# Error: g++.exe: No such file or directory g++.exe: fatal error: no input files in Visual studio code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw, dev-c++

There is no error in my code, and I have configured **Mingw** in Environment Variables but showing this error. I've created this file in **Dev C++** and *is running well in it*. The Error is :

```
g++.exe: error: Calculator: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: .cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

I have inserted the image for reference.
[image]

Files that I created in **Visual studio code** are running well and I've tried copying the code of this file in a new file and that ran. So should I do this with all the files I've created with Dev C++ or there is another method to resolve this issue?

Comment: The error indicates that g++ can't find your  source code. Maybe the folder where your files are have a space in the path and you are having a problem where it needs to quote the path. It would help if you showed the text of the build commands.

Comment: Building is controlled by your `tasks.json` file. The instructions  on this is here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: Your problem appears that there is a space between Calculator and .cpp. Rename this file to remove the space from the file name. My advice is to never use spaces in paths or file names when programming in c++ or c. The reason is compiling usually involves a command line utility and spaces on the command line separate arguments. So g++ is trying to compile a file named exactly `Calculator` and a file named  `.cpp` not `Calculator .cpp` and neither of these 2 files exist.

Comment: "I have configured Mingw in Environment Variables"  How? Did you change PATH and if so what did you add?

Comment: @drescherjm, please add your comment to answers to other people with the same problem get help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the filename for your source file is `Calculator .cpp` which contains a space. This is problematic for languages that use command line compilers like c or c++ because on the command line a space separates arguments so without quotes around the filename your compiler sees `Calculator` and `.cpp` as 2 separate files instead of `Calculator .cpp`. The easy fix for this is to rename the file to remove the space. I highly recommend avoiding spaces in paths or file names with c or c++ regardless of how you build to avoid issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

Bro the problem is with the file name there should be no space in the file name you saved it as Calculator .cpp that's why it is showing error try saving it as Calculator.cpp

Answer (score 0):

you executed the compiler, but you didn't tell it what to compile and from where to compile.
Check where u have save ur program and In terminal section which shows actual directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the file name. Remove the space from Calculator .cpp
Even if you name your file as new code.cpp there is a possibility it will show the same error, you have to rename it to newcode.cpp

Comment: This is correct, but drescherjm already posted basically the same thing 1 year ago.